# Proving (AAA) <-> (SAS)

Tags: geometry

Does anyone have a clue how I can prove that (Angle - Angle - Angle) <-> (Side - Angle - Side) for the similarity of triangles? I don´t know where to start?

/Alex

Comment: Can you clarify what the triples mean?

Comment: Angle-Angle-Angle gives you similarly, but side-angle-side gives you congruence.  They are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.

Construct the given triangles so that they have an angle in common. Then use the [intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) and its converse.